# "ping" isn't allowed to be executed

Tags: python, paramiko

When I try to use Paramiko to exec any command I get

> "[COMMAND]" isn't allowed to be executed.

But If I do that by using Putty it works fine, any idea what can be causing this?

Paramiko:

```
>>>ssh.connect('server',port=22,username='user',password='pass'
>>>stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2')
>>>output = stdout.readlines()
>>>print output
[]
>>>error = stderr.readlines()
>>>print error
>>>u'"ping" isn\'t allowed to be executed.\n'
```

Putty:

```
user@server:~$ ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=57 time=15.928 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=57 time=15.661 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 15.661/15.794/15.928 ms
```

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174470/how-to-enable-using-commands-on-remote-host-using-ssh-without-password) at http://unix.stackexchange.com. Try putting the command itself in double quotes: `'"ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2"'`.

Comment: can you try with some other command, like `ls` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeap tyhe same happens with every command

Comment: i guess your error coming from BadAuthenticationType, "if public-key authentication isn’t allowed by the server for this user"

Comment: @AriGold well, whenever I want to ssh to this server I use Putty, with username and password. I've never used a key before.

Comment: the reason is the type of the error for me, if the command is corrupt you will get something like ['Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.\r\n']....again i am not sure

Comment: What I don't know is if this is happening because a config on the server of because of the way my command is arriving to the server.. I am not the admin but I thought that using Paramiko was the same as using Putty from the server's view.

Comment: can you `echo $SHELL` in the putty connection? maybe it is caused by special default shell or PATH?

Comment: @CSJ I can do echo "whatever here" and I also tried with double quotes

Comment: @Raulnd, please paste the result of `echo $SHELL`, I'd like to know the shell you use, Don't use other string, just `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @Raulnd, got it, that's what I mean special shell you are using, then it should be related to `sudosh` or `PATH` things. Could you paste the result of `echo $PATH` both in putty and code, then check the 2 results are same or not?

Comment: In Putty: **/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin**

In Paramiko: 
**[u'"echo" isn\'t allowed to be executed.\n']**

Comment: @Raulnd, hmm, then it is related to `sudosh`, I am not sure why you use it as default shell. if you change the default sehll `chsh -s /bin/bash` and run your code, I guess the problem would be gone. However, you still need to confirm the reason you are using `sudosh`

Comment: but what is the difference between using putty and using paramiko? I thought both would be the same from the server's point of view. @CSJ

Comment: @Raulnd, sorry I am not familiar to sudosh, and seems there are some similar discussion [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/sudosh2/mailman/sudosh2-discuss/thread/4A833B03.5070508@shortcutsolutions.net/), looks like you need to specify some allow commands in `/etc/sudosh.conf` but it is `sudosh2`...

Comment: I had to use ssh.invoke_shell() ... but It seems @CSJ is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paramiko's `exec_command(cmd)` will invoke `/the/login/shell -c cmd` to run the command which is similar to `ssh user@host cmd`. If your login shell on the remote server does not support `-c` then `exec_command()` would fail. So before using `exec_command()` I usually first try `ssh user@host cmd` from the command line.

`invoke_shell()` would work because it starts an interactive session just like you connect to the server manually with `PuTTY`.