# Using Channels with Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am working on converting a tool from Ruby to Python, and the Ruby version uses [Net::SSH](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net/SSH) to connect to a remote host, and send commands and retrieve responses/data. I have been using paramiko in the Python counterpart, but I'm confused as to the purpose of [Channels in paramiko.](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/channel.html) From what I've read so far, it seems to me that a channel (which uses a [paramiko Transport](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport)) is used to keep a persistent connection to SSH rather than executing a command and then terminating the connection.

Is a Channel required? What is the stack required to open a persistent SSH connection to a host as to send and receive multiple commands sequentially and get the responses, then when finished manually close the connection?

These are the two main lines I'm having trouble translating into Python, because I'm not sure if a Ruby "Channel" directly maps to a paramiko "Channel":

```
@ssh_connection = Net::SSH.start(@linux_server_name, 
                        @server_user_name, 
                        :password => @password, 
                        :paranoid => false)
```

and later on in the code

```
@channel = @ssh_connection.open_channel do |new_channel|
```

**Edit:** To further explain my question, I was able to connect to a remote host using paramiko and execute multiple sequential commands and get their results without using a transport or a channel, so again, what are the reasons for using a Channel in paramiko?

```
def connect(self):
    ssh_connection = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_connection.connect(self.linux_server_name)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_connection.exec_command("ls -l")
    print(stdout.readlines())
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_connection.exec_command("ls -l /tmp")
    print(stdout.readlines())
    ssh_connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec_command()` is enough if the SSH server supports running commands (like `ssh user@host "cmd; cmd; ..."`. But some SSH servers (e.g. network devices like switches, routers, ...) only supports starting an interactive session. Then you need to use `invoke_shell()` which returns a *Channel*.

*Transport* and *Channel* are all SSH terms (other than Paramiko's). See following RFCs for more info:

- [rfc4251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251) - The SSH Protocol Architecture
- [rfc4252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252) - The SSH Authentication Protocol
- [rfc4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253) - The SSH Transport Layer Protocol
- [rfc4254](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254) - The SSH Connection Protocol

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570124/ping-isnt-allowed-to-be-executed , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183971/paramiko-session-times-out-but-i-need-to-execute-a-lot-of-commands , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090445/paramiko-exec-command-not-executing-and-returns-extra-params-found-in-cli

Comment: Is the `invoke_shell()` what you would use, for example, when a you need to use a pty? Seems like that would be the case...

Comment: not exactly. `exec_command(command, get_pty=True)` can also get a pty. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111173/

Comment: `invoke_shell()` can do all `exec_command()` can do. so try `exec_command()` first (which is easier to use) and if it does not work then use `invoke_shell()`.