# Paramiko SSH works first time but does not work the second time unless wait

Tags: python, unix, ssh, expect, paramiko

I'm using paramiko ssh on python. It works fine the first time as shown in the following log:

```
.... more logs above...    
Authentication (password) successful!
[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 0 opened.
[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
[chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 1 opened.
[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
[chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
Ignoring message for dead channel 0
Ignoring message for dead channel 0
Ignoring message for dead channel 0
... starts running expect script and works fine...
[chan 1] EOF received (1)
[chan 1] EOF sent (1)
[chan 2] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 2] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 2 opened.
[chan 2] Sesch channel 2 request ok
EOF in transport thread
```

And I run again right after I finish this script, and it doesn't work with the following log:

```
... more logs above...
Authentication (password) successful!
[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 0 opened.
[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
[chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 1 opened.
[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
[chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
[chan 1] EOF received (1)
[chan 2] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 1] EOF sent (1)
[chan 2] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 2 opened.
Ignoring message for dead channel 0
Ignoring message for dead channel 0
[chan 2] Sesch channel 2 request ok
EOF in transport thread
... does not run rest and ends here...
```

Here is an example of my code (not exact):

```
import paramiko
import logging

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
ssh.connect(host, username=usr, password=pwd)

prompt="{\\\\$ $}"
expect_script='set timeout -1\n' \
              'spawn sudo -i -u {0}\n' \
              'expect -exact \\"\\\\[sudo\\\\] password for {1}: \\"\n' \
              'send -- \\"{2}\\\\r\\"\n' \
              'set prompt_re {3}\n' \
              'expect -re \\$prompt_re\n' \
              'send \\"shell_script.sh\\\\r\\"\n' \
              'expect -re \\$prompt_re\n' \
              '\n' \
              .format(another_user,usr,pwd,prompt)
ssh.exec_command('echo "{}" > test.exp'.format(expect_script))
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('expect test.exp')
for line in stdout:
    logging.debug(line.strip('\n'))
ssh.close()
```

I think it has something to do with session not closing properly at the end. I need to run this python script multiple times and it only seems to work if I wait ~ 5 minutes between each time I run this. I added the expect script in the code in case it might be the cause of the problem. Could it be because expect script is still running, and I try to start another session? Each time I run this, the host and user is the same.

Comment: not a good idea to use Expect in python. u can just use python's pexpect.

Comment: @pynexj I'm using Windows so pexpect won't work.

Comment: then u can use paramiko itself to send commands to remote server and check the corresonding output by yourself which is much easier than embedding Expect code in python.

Comment: @pynexj what do you mean by "check the corresponding output by yourself"? You mean manually? How would you input password without using Expect?

Comment: u can start an shell with paramiko and interact (read/write) with it with py code. (search `paramiko invoke_shell`)

Comment: if u have only one command to run on the ssh server than `stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo ...', get_pty=True)` is also enough. then u can read from `stdout` (and `stderr`) and write to `stdin`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508213/using-channels-with-paramiko/45512023#45512023

Comment: @pynexj oh yea... using `invoke_shell` works and easier than doing my method. Will rewrite my code. Thanks!